# Playing iTunes purchased movies using safari - DRM protected content iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios8, drm

In my application i want to play iTunes purchased movies (DRM Protected content) for that what i did is passing the HTTP URL to safari and safari will play the DRM protected file.This HTTP URL is pointing the DRM protected file.I'm opening safari in the normal way by [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url] method. It is working fine in iOS 7 and prior versions. Unfortunately this feature is not working in iOS 8, it opens safari and showing play symbol with cross mark. Please suggest me any workaround to achieve the solution in iOS 8.

Comment: Sorry, Apple seems to have decided to disable playback of DRM protected video in Safari in iOS 8. Attempts have been made to get Apple to fix this, but Apple is not moving on it.